# What is armor "properties" on the default character sheet?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-sheets

On page 2, the AC Items table at the top has a "properties" column.

What goes in that slot of the character sheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's for special properties, primarily the [special properties](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor) on magic armor. [Wild](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/wild) is an example of one. You can also use that space for any other details that don't fit elsewhere, but it's mostly used for special properties on magic armor.

Comment: Expanding on the above mentioned "other details": I usually put the maximum allowed DEX bonus there, since its designated field was scrapped from 3.5 to PF.